# Query is running too slow?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a MySQL query with left join it giving me result in 28 seconds when I remove and condition with left join then it working in one second can any one tell me what is the issue in my query and how it will be modified?

```
  select *  
  FROM regist_queue rq
  left join appoint ap
  on rq.token_number = ap.daily_ticket_no 
  and rq.LocationId = 15800
  and ap.LocationId = 15800
  and date(rq.QueueDate) = CURRENT_DATE()
  and date(ap.dAppDate) = date(now())
  left join patient pr
  on ap.iPatID = pr.IPatID
  left join gender ge
  on pr.vGender = ge.iGenderID
  where ifnull(ap.isDel,0) = 0
  and ifnull(ap.is_referred,0) != 1
  and (ap.LocationId  = 15800 or rq.LocationId = 15800 )  
  order by rq.token_number asc;
```

I also applied indexes on all searched parameters and where joins are applied.
Explain plan of query.
MySQL Query Plan:
[image: MySql Query Plan]

Comment: `Explain` of command would be useful.

Comment: i have updated my query with query plan image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your purpose is not pretty clear to me. For an example in the join `and rq.LocationId = 15800
  and ap.LocationId = 15800` 
and in the where clause `and (ap.LocationId  = 15800 or rq.LocationId = 15800 )`

what my suggestion is to have something like this.

in the left join  `rq.LocationId = ap.LocationId`
and in the where clause `ap.LocationId = 15800`

it is hard to evaluate the performance without having the real data.

Comment: can you please change the entire query with what you are suggesting.

Comment: select *  
  FROM regist_queue rq
  left join appoint ap
  on rq.token_number = ap.daily_ticket_no 
  and rq.LocationId = ap.LocationId
  and date(rq.QueueDate) = CURRENT_DATE()
  and date(ap.dAppDate) = date(now())
  left join patient pr
  on ap.iPatID = pr.IPatID
  left join gender ge
  on pr.vGender = ge.iGenderID
  where ifnull(ap.isDel,0) = 0
  and ifnull(ap.is_referred,0) != 1
  and (ap.LocationId  = 15800)  
  order by rq.token_number asc;

Comment: or you may want change the where condition as follows

(ap.LocationId  = 15800 or rq.LocationId = 15800)

Comment: thank you @Lakshitha my problem has resolved with your given solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL `with (nolock)` in sql query

like :

```
select *  
  FROM regist_queue rq with (nolock)
  left join appoint ap with (nolock)
  on rq.token_number = ap.daily_ticket_no 
  and rq.LocationId = 15800
  and ap.LocationId = 15800
  and date(rq.QueueDate) = CURRENT_DATE()
  and date(ap.dAppDate) = date(now())
  left join patient pr with (nolock)
  on ap.iPatID = pr.IPatID
  left join gender ge with (nolock)
  on pr.vGender = ge.iGenderID
  where ifnull(ap.isDel,0) = 0
  and ifnull(ap.is_referred,0) != 1
  and (ap.LocationId  = 15800 or rq.LocationId = 15800 )  
  order by rq.token_number asc;
```

Comment: with no lock giving me syntax error. incorrect syntax near with expected end of input.

Comment: i read it and implemented SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED  for mysql but its taking same time to execute i updated my question with query plan image.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is Cartesian join....

base on the three predicate starts with on .........,

i think the sql statement does not based on your real purpose...

Comment: is that an answer?